# python parse a list for a version number

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a json file with different objects, each object have a version value like:

"version": [ 2, 10, 5, 1 ]

I would like to filter objects based on the version value, I'm interested in only getting a range. Example

Get all objects with a version > 2.5.3.10 and version < 3.0

I appreciate the help.

Regards

Comment: Have you written any code?  Are you using a JSON library?  What's the rest of the data structure look like?

Answer (score 1):

Lexicographical ordering is usually not adequate for comparing versions. You can use eg. LooseVersion from distutils.version to get usable comparisons.

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

assert LooseVersion("10.1.1") < LooseVersion("100.1.1")
```

There are a few subtle problems with using the version in the list directly:

```
[1,0] < [1,0,0] == True
[1,0] == [1,0,0] == False
```

This should cover all the edge cases:

```
LooseVersion(".".join(version)) > LooseVersion("2.5.3.10") and LooseVersion(".".join(version)) < LooseVersion("3.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I just noticed I can do:

```
if data['version'] > [2, 5, 3, 10]:
    print "that is old"
```

Python does the math automatically, gotta love it :)

Comment: Yes, the important part from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types): `The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.`